# Is it possible to assign a side_effect to a class member variable in python when patching using the unittest module?

Tags: python, pytest, python-unittest, monkeypatching

Is it possible to patch over a class instance variable and force it to return a different value each time that it's referenced? specifically, I'm interested in doing this with the **side_effect** parameter

- I know that when patching over a method it is possible to assign a **side_effect** to a mock method. If you set the **side_effect** to be a list it will iterate through the list returning a different value each time it is called.
- I would like to do the same thing with a class instance variable but cannot get it to work and I cannot see any documentation to suggest whether this is or is not possible

#### Example

```
from unittest.mock import patch

def run_test():
    myClass = MyClass()
    for i in range(2):
        print(myClass.member_variable)

class MyClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.member_variable = None

@patch('test_me.MyClass.member_variable',side_effect=[1,2], create=True)
def test_stuff(my_mock):
    run_test()
    assert False
```

#### Output

```
-------------- Captured stdout call ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
None
None
```

#### Desired Output

```
-------------- Captured stdout call ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1
2
```

- To be clear - I'm aware that I can wrap **member_variable** in a **get_member_variable method()**. That is not my question. I just want to know if you can patch a member variable with a side_effect.

Comment: AFAIK `side_effect` will only work on callables

Comment: @yorodm Thanks for your response. Do you have any documentation about this that you can direct me to?

Comment: Is all over the place in [mock.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/unittest/mock.py)

Answer (score 0):

`side_effect` can be either a function, an iterable or an exception (https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.side_effect). I think that's the reason why it's not working.

Another way to test this would be:

```py
>>> class Class:
...     member_variable = None
...
>>> with patch('__main__.Class') as MockClass:
...     instance = MockClass.return_value
...     instance.member_variable = 'foo'
...     assert Class() is instance
...     assert Class().member_variable == 'foo'
...
```

Here's the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch

Comment: Yes, I have tried setting side_effect to an iterable.  That's exactly what I want to do. It works on methods, but I can't get it to work on attributes

Answer (score 0):

In the case of the example you set I could not make the change the way I thought, you may have more items in this class and with this idea can help you.

Not the best option to side effect on an attribute but it worked as I needed it.

PS: I ended up putting as an example the code that brought me to your question.

Example:

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# !/usr/bin/env python3

import requests

from src.metaclasses.singleton import Singleton
from src.services.logger import new_logger
from src.exceptions.too_many_retries import TooManyRetries
from src.exceptions.unavailable_url import UnavailableURL

LOG = new_logger(__name__)


class PostbackService(metaclass=Singleton):
    def __init__(self):
        self.session = requests.session()

    def make_request(self, method, url, headers, data=None, retry=0):
        r = self.session.request(method, url, data=data, headers=headers)

        if r.status_code != 200:
            if retry < 3:
                return self.make_request(method, url, headers, data, retry + 1)
            message = f"Error performing request for url: {url}"
            LOG.error(message)
            raise TooManyRetries(message)

        return r.json()
```

Test:

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# !/usr/bin/env python3
from unittest import TestCase
from unittest.mock import patch, MagicMock

from src.services.postback import PostbackService
from src.exceptions.too_many_retries import TooManyRetries
from src.exceptions.unavailable_url import UnavailableURL


class TestPostbackService(TestCase):
    @patch("src.services.postback.requests")
    def setUp(self, mock_requests) -> None:
        mock_requests.return_value = MagicMock()
        self.pb = PostbackService()

    def test_make_request(self):
        self.pb.session.request.return_value = MagicMock()

        url = "http://mock.io"
        header = {"mock-header": "mock"}
        data = {"mock-data": "mock"}
        mock_json = {"mock-json": "mock"}

        def _def_mock(value):
            """
            Returns a MagicMock with the status code changed for each request, so you can test the retry behavior of the application.
            """
            mock = MagicMock()
            mock.status_code = value
            mock.json.return_value = mock_json
            return mock

        self.pb.session.request.side_effect = [
            _def_mock(403),
            _def_mock(404),
            _def_mock(200),
        ]
        self.assertEqual(self.pb.make_request("GET", url, header, data), mock_json)

        self.pb.session.request.side_effect = [
            _def_mock(403),
            _def_mock(404),
            _def_mock(404),
            _def_mock(404),
        ]
        with self.assertRaises(TooManyRetries):
            self.pb.make_request("GET", url, header, data)
```

As you can see I recreated magicmock by changing the side effect of each one to what I wanted to do. It was not beautiful code and super pythonic, but it worked as expected.
I used as base to create this magicmock object the link that @rsarai sent from the unittest documentation.